# Extract drivers from ROM directly?

Tags: custom-roms, samsung, samsung-galaxy-s-5

My girlfriend recently bought a Samsung Galaxy S5 which, after paying over 500 bucks for it, turned out to be a counterfeit s5.

Obviously the scammer didn't get back to us and as much as this is a good lesson to learn (don't be cheap and rely on Kijiji!), we want to make the most out of the phone as well. As such I am hoping to port one of the custom OS on it as the OS that came with the machine is pretty old (Android 4.2 I believe).

The problem is all the hardware signatures were obviously obscured and there is no way (at least I am aware of) to know the exact hardware pieces. My only hope is to somehow being able to extract the drivers out of the existing ROM and see where I can go.

Is there any way I can do that? If not, is there anyway you would recommend to make compiling of custom ROM possible without knowing the exact configuration of the phone (other than having a original factory ROM on hand and obviously the physical unit as well)?

Comment: By saying drivers you mean firmware? Kernel? Baseband?

Comment: @joaquin I guess I mean the drivers for the radio and baseband and all that. Basically whatever device-dependent component I need to compile the custom ROM.